# How to get the view coordinates in relativelayout in android

Tags: android, coordinates, android-relativelayout

I want to get position  of view located inside a `RelativeLayout`  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getLocationOnScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) method to detect position of your view and layout on screen. Then just calculate relative coordinates.